# how to post by id array when the value change in the form , is go with id

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

i want to post this when i change the value in radio button in the form pop up  here is my html :

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="injected">
                            <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef class="radioButtonVacXin">
                                <p style="width:50px;">
                                {{'VacXin.Injected' | translate}}  
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                {{'VacXin.notInjected' | translate}} 
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                {{'VacXin.refuseInjected' | translate}}
                                </p>
                            </mat-header-cell>
                            <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let item" class="radioButtonVacXin">
                                <mat-radio-group class="w-180" class="radioButtonVacXin" fxLayout="row" [(ngModel)]="item.injected" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                                    <mat-radio-button class="w-60"   [value]="1" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
                                    </mat-radio-button>
                                    <mat-radio-button class="w-60" [value]="0" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                                    </mat-radio-button>
                                    <mat-radio-button class="w-60"  [value]="2" fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
                                    </mat-radio-button>
                                </mat-radio-group>
                            </mat-cell> 
                        </ng-container>
```

and here is my file ts looks like  :

```
export class AddStaffVacXinComponent implements OnInit {
    item: any = {};
    form: FormGroup;
    formErrors: any;
    isEdit: boolean;
    comboData: any[] = [];
    allManufactory: any[] = [];
    FilterManufactory: any[] = [];
    displayedVacXin = ['injected'];
    params: any = {};
    dataSourceVacXin: MatTableDataSource<any> = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
    employeeId : any ={};
constructor(
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private translate: TranslatePipe,
    public staffVacXin: StaffVacxinService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddStaffVacXinComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    if (this.data.item) {
        this.item = Object.assign({ }, data.item);
        this.employeeId = this.item.id;
        
        this.isEdit = true;
    }
    else {
        this.isEdit = false;
    }
   }
ngOnInit() {
    let params = this.params;
    this.params = this.employeeId;
    this.staffVacXin.getDetail(this.params).then(res => {
        debugger
        this.dataSourceVacXin.data = res;
    });
}
processResponse(res) {
    if (res) {
        this.snackBar.open(
            this.translate.transform("Common.Msg.UpdateSuccess"),
            "OK",
            {
                verticalPosition: "top",
                duration: 2000,
            }
        );
        this.dialogRef.close(res);
    } else {
        this.snackBar.open(
            this.translate.transform("Common.Msg.UpdateError"),
            "OK",
            {
                verticalPosition: "top",
                duration: 2000,
            }
        );
    }
}

save() {
    debugger
    if (!this.data.isEdit) {
        this.staffVacXin.post(this.item).then(rs => {
            if (rs) {
                this.processResponse(true);
            } else {
                this.processResponse(false);
            }
        })
    } else {
        this.staffVacXin.put(this.item, this.item.id).then(rs => {
            if (rs) {
                this.processResponse(true);
            } else {
                this.processResponse(false);

            }
        })
    }
}
```

And here is my api look like its get by employeeId when inject= 0 is notInjected , inject= 1  is Injected and inject= 3 is refuseInjected i want to post when i change value in the form

```
[
  {
    "name": "HEBERBIOVAC",
    "inject": 1,
    "note": "namhg",
    "employeeId": "7f11a477-e672-439c-a40c-acfa14d8122f",
    "vaccinId": "a41f12e5-7e67-45b8-a344-08dacdf4156b"
  },
  {
    "name": "PRIORIX",
    "inject": 0,
    "note": "namhg",
    "vaccinId": "5d0546dc-cdc0-4629-a345-08dacdf4156b",
    "employeeId": "7f11a477-e672-439c-a40c-acfa14d8122f"
  },
  {
    "name": "nnn",
    "inject": 0,
    "note": "test",
    "vaccinId": "8ab9a6b9-b956-462e-a346-08dacdf4156b",
    "employeeId": "7f11a477-e672-439c-a40c-acfa14d8122f"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i know the answer is i forgot to get the employeeId in each record in api then i need to put in it :

```
 ngOnInit() {
        debugger;
        let params = this.params;
        this.params = this.employeeId;
        
        this.staffVacXin.getDetail(this.params).then((res) => {
            
            for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                const element = res[i];
                element.employeeId = this.params;
            }
            this.dataSourceVacXin.data = res;
        });
    }
```